# Python subprocess on Windows: Launching subprocess "cmd.exe" and giving it a bat-file, stops the main process execution

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, cmd, subprocess, popen

I intend to run a Windows `.bat` with `cmd.exe` using the `subprocess` module from Python. To make things simple, I've created a *minimal and reproducible example* that you can run on your own computer.
First I'll show its setup. Then you'll get the code, after which I explain what is going wrong.

### 1. The setup

I got a Windows 10 computer with `Python 3.7` installed and `PyQt5`. For the reproducible example, I made a folder with three files:

[image]

The file **my_subprocess.py** is a python script that spawns a window with a label showing a counter. The file **my_subprocess.bat** is a very simple bat file that executes this python file.

[image]

The file **my_mainprocess.py** uses the Python `subprocess` module to run the bat-file in `cmd.exe`. After launching the subprocess, it keeps listening to the subprocess output channel, and shows the output in a window:

[image]

### 2. The code

**my_subprocess.py:**

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class SubprocessWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("MY SUBPROCESS WINDOW")
        # 1. OUTER FRAME
        self.__frm = QFrame()
        self.__frm.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.__frm.setStyleSheet("QFrame { background-color:#eeeeec; border-color: #2e3436; }")
        self.__lyt = QVBoxLayout()
        self.__frm.setLayout(self.__lyt)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.__frm)
        self.show()
        # 2. WIDGETS
        self.__cntr = 0
        self.__myLabel = QLabel(f"cntr: {self.__cntr}")
        self.__myLabel.setFixedHeight(40)
        self.__myLabel.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.__myLabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color:#ffffff; border-color: #2e3436; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; font: 16pt; }")
        self.__lyt.addWidget(self.__myLabel)
        self.count()
        return

    def count(self):
        self.__cntr += 1
        self.__myLabel.setText(f"cntr: {self.__cntr}")
        print(f"cntr: {self.__cntr}")
        QTimer.singleShot(500, self.count)
        return

if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Plastique'))
    myGUI = SubprocessWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**my_subprocess.bat:**

```sh
@echo off
ECHO Start Subprocess
SETLOCAL
python my_subprocess.py
ECHO Finish Subprocess
```

**my_mainprocess.py:**

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys, os, subprocess

class MainprocessWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 500, 600, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("MY MAIN PROCESS WINDOW")
        # 1. OUTER FRAME
        self.__frm = QFrame()
        self.__frm.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.__frm.setStyleSheet("QFrame { background-color:#fce94f; border-color: #2e3436; }")
        self.__lyt = QVBoxLayout()
        self.__frm.setLayout(self.__lyt)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.__frm)
        self.show()
        # 2. WIDGETS
        self.__cntr = 0
        self.__myTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.__myTextEdit.setStyleSheet("""
                QPlainTextEdit {
                    color: #ffffffff;
                    font: 12pt;
                    background: #ff000000;
                    border-width: 1px;
                    border-color: #ff888a85;
                    border-style: solid;
                    border-radius: 2px;
                    padding: 1px;
                    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
                }
                """)
        self.__myTextEdit.setFixedHeight(290)
        self.__myTextEdit.setFixedWidth(590)
        self.__lyt.addWidget(self.__myTextEdit)
        self.__proc = None
        QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.start_subprocess)
        return

    def start_subprocess(self):
        self.activateWindow()
        self.__proc = subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe", shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        command = "my_subprocess.bat\n"
        self.__proc.stdin.write(command)
        self.__proc.stdin.flush()
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.catch_output)
        return

    def catch_output(self):
        if self.__proc.poll() is None:
            self.__proc.stdout.flush()
            output_msg = self.__proc.stdout.readline()
            self.__myTextEdit.appendPlainText(output_msg)
        else:
            self.__myTextEdit.appendPlainText("Subprocess dead")
        QTimer.singleShot(300, self.catch_output)
        return

if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Plastique'))
    myGUI = MainprocessWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### 3. Run the code

Please copy-paste the code into the files **my_subprocess.py**, **my_subprocess.bat** and **my_mainprocess.py**. Open a console, and navigate to the folder containing these files. Run `python my_mainprocess.py` starting the main process, which in turn starts the subprocess. You should see the two windows shown at the top: the first belongs to the subprocess, the second one to the main process.

### 4. The problem

**4.1 The main process hangs**
I believe both the main process and the subprocess should both run simultaneously. Look at the code of the main process. There is no blocking call anywhere. It simply catches the output on the `stdout` channel and prints it on the window:

```py
def catch_output(self):
    if self.__proc.poll() is None:
        self.__proc.stdout.flush()
        output_msg = self.__proc.stdout.readline()
        self.__myTextEdit.appendPlainText(output_msg)
    else:
        self.__myTextEdit.appendPlainText("Subprocess dead")
    QTimer.singleShot(300, self.catch_output)
    return
```

However, the main process hangs until you stop the subprocess (by closing the subprocess window). Then, the main process continues and prints all the output. Why?

**4.2 The main process crashes**
And things get worse. After the main process finishes outputting the standard out channel, it crashes.
I believe I know why - but I got no solution. The call `self.__proc.poll()` should return `None` if the subprocess is alive and a number otherwise. Instead, I noticed it just keeps returning `None`, even if the subprocess is already dead and buried long ago.
How do I circumvent this problem?

---

**UPDATE:**
Adding `sys.stdout.flush()` in the `my_subprocess.py` code after each print statement certainly helps. But it is not a good solution, because `my_subprocess.py` is merely a representative for any potential program that can run as a subprocess. For most of such programs, we don't have access to the source code.
In other words, the solution should only focus on what can be done in `my_mainprocess.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `MainprocessWindow.start_subprocess` to:

```py
    def start_subprocess(self):
        self.activateWindow()
        command = "cmd.exe /c my_subprocess.bat\n"
        self.__proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.catch_output)
        return
```

and add line `sys.stdout.fulsh()` to the `SubprocessWindow.count` like so:

```py
    def count(self):
        self.__cntr += 1
        self.__myLabel.setText(f"cntr: {self.__cntr}")
        print(f"cntr: {self.__cntr}")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        QTimer.singleShot(500, self.count)
        return
```

Comment: Hi @Matic,
Your suggestion on start the subprocess differently is certainly helpful. However, I cannot add `sys.stdout.flush()` to the subprocess code itself. That's because this subprocess is a representative of any potential program that can be run as a subprocess. I forgot to mention this in my question.